# Git not working correctly in PyCharm terminal (PowerShell)

Tags: git, powershell, terminal, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've run into a problem with using PowerShell embedded in the PyCharm. I cannot use git from this terminal even though it works perfectly fine with PowerShell opened in the normal way (not in the PyCharm).

Then when I run:

```
git fetch origin
```

I get:

```
bash: cat: command not found
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 127)
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://nme@foo.com': No error
```

I'm using PowerShell version is 5.1.

Does someone know where this issue could come from?

Comment: I've managed to identify the source of the problem. The reason for this strange behavior is having the option Activate virtualenv (Settings->
->Tools->Terminal) checked. PyCharm runs the "activate.bat" script instead of running Activate.ps1 from the virtual_env/Scripts directory.

I guess for now the only option is to add a line activating virtual environment to the profile.ps1 file (PowerShell equivallent of .bashrc).